# Is there any specific order of app.router , express.urlencoded and express.static(__public + "/public");

Tags: node.js, express

Is there any specific order in which these three commands should be written in the `app.configure` function?

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I am asking this because when I change their order , I sometimes get an `ENOENT` error or some middleware doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the default app.js file express creates the order is

```
app.use(express.bodyParser()); // or app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

So I guess this is the right way...